# Get Spannable String from EditText

Tags: android, spannablestring

I have set a `SpannableString` to an `EditText`, now I want to get this text from the `EditText` and get its markup information. I tried like this:

```
SpannableStringBuilder spanStr = (SpannableStringBuilder) et.getText();
int boldIndex = spanStr.getSpanStart(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD));
int italicIndex = spanStr.getSpanStart(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC));
```

But it gives index `-1` for both bold and italic, although it is showing text with italic and bold.

Please help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the code you've posted, you're passing new spans to spanStr and asking it to find them. You'll need to have a reference to the instances of those spans that are actually applied. If that's not feasible or you don't want to track spans directly, you can simply call 
[getSpans](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html#getSpans%28int,%20int,%20java.lang.Class%3CT%3E%29%20%22getSpans) to get all the spans applied. You can then filter that array for what you want.

If you don't care about the spans in particular, you can also just call [Html.toHtml(spanStr)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#toHtml%28android.text.Spanned%29) to get an HTML tagged version.

**edit**: to add code example

This will grab all applied StyleSpans which is what you want.

```
    /* From the Android docs on StyleSpan: "Describes a style in a span. 
     * Note that styles are cumulative -- both bold and italic are set in 
     * separate spans, or if the base is bold and a span calls for italic, 
     * you get bold italic. You can't turn off a style from the base style."*/
StyleSpan[] mSpans = et.getText().getSpans(0, et.length(), StyleSpan.class);
```

Here's a link to the [StyleSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/StyleSpan.html) docs.

To pick out the spans you want if you have various spans mixed in to a collection/array, you can use `instanceof` to figure out what type of spans you've got. This snippet will check if a particular span `mSpan` is an instance of StyleSpan and then print its start/end indices and flags. The flags are constants that describe how the span ends behave such as: Do they include and apply styling to the text at the start/end indices or only to text input at an index inside the start/end range).

```
 if (mSpan instanceof StyleSpan) { 
        int start = et.getSpanStart(mSpan);
        int end = et.getSpanEnd(mSpan);
        int flag = et.getSpanFlags(mSpan);
        Log.i("SpannableString Spans", "Found StyleSpan at:\n" +
                "Start: " + start + 
                 "\n End: " + end + 
                 "\n Flag(s): " + flag);
 }
```

Comment: I am able to get HTML tagged version, but not able to get using getSpans. Can you provide some code to get  e.g bold span index. i have set the bold span same as i tried getting it.

Comment: how do you use getSpans?

Comment: @pskink
Object[] objArray = spanStr.getSpans(0, spanStr.length()-1, Object.class); it gives me array of classes , but how to found the index for that class?

Comment: @pskink index where from bold text is started

Comment: see Spanned, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html#getSpanStart(java.lang.Object)

Comment: @pskink I added some examples which should answer your question.

Comment: @KMDev i know how to deal with Spanned/spans, it was the question to the OP since he had some problems with getSpans()

Comment: @pskink Ah, I interpreted that incorrectly. I'll edit the answer. :)

Comment: @KMDev no problema amigo